# Access HashMap data from another class

Tags: java, arraylist, data-structures, hashmap

I have a class in which I have a populated HashMap and ArrayList. I need to access the the keys and values from the HashMap and ArrayList in my other classes, when I do so, the program returns a NULL?

My HashMap is in this class:

```
package championsLeagueTeamGenerator;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class topTier extends GroupStages {

    public static ArrayList <Integer> x = new ArrayList <Integer>();
    public static HashMap <Integer, String> xx = new HashMap();


    public static void firstPot() {

        x.add(1);
        x.add(2);
        x.add(3);
        x.add(4);
        x.add(5);
        x.add(6);
        x.add(7);
        x.add(8);

        Collections.shuffle(x);

        xx.put(x.get(0), "Manchester United");
        xx.put(x.get(1), "Barcelona");
        xx.put(x.get(2), "Real Madrid");
        xx.put(x.get(3), "Paris St Germain");
        xx.put(x.get(4), "Bayern Munich");
        xx.put(x.get(5), "Juventus");
        xx.put(x.get(6), "Chelsea");
        xx.put(x.get(7), "Liverpool");

        System.out.println(xx);

 }
```

And I want to access it in this class:

```
package championsLeagueTeamGenerator;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

public class GroupStages {

    public static ArrayList <String> groupA = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void groupOne() {         
        System.out.print(topTier.xx.get(1));        
    }   
}
```

but the program returns NULL, why is that?

Comment: Where `topTier` comes from?

Answer (score 0):

You have missed out on executing firstPot() static method in the topTier class.

This will give you the correct output.

---

```
public static void groupOne() {

    topTier.firstPot();
    System.out.print(topTier.xx.get(1));

   }
```

Comment: `topTier` is not declared nor is accesible from `GroupStages` class

Comment: Thank you @VaibhavSingh, its worked. just for my own personal development, do you have to declare the method before you can use it. e.g.  topTier.firstPot();.